# primefaces schedule repeat day with different values

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, schedule

I want to know if there is anything I can use with primefaces schedule or anything similiar preferably from primefaces, to be able to set diferent events for the same day, I explain my situation a little better:

I have multiple boardrooms and I have a filter that loads the schedule with the information for each boardroom and the events that it has scheduled, but I want to be able to see multiple boardrooms at the same time.

My idea is to have multiple schedules and each one load a boardroom event, I don't want to have a single schedule show with different colors each boardroom. I want them to be separated, is it posible?

[example](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbarsilverlight/img/SilverlightCalendarMultiResourceView.png)

Answer (score 0):

It can be to late .... Hope this idea can help someone in the futur !

If I understand, you need to cut the day with different columns depend on your boardrooms number.
Perhaps you can do that with css style. When you create event, you can affect a css style. 
Exemple for 3 boardroom :

```
.firstBoardRoom { left :0% !important; right : 67% !important }
.middleBoardRoom { left :34% !important; right : 34% !important }
.lastBoardRoom { left :67% !important; right : 0% !important }
```

Or something like this